# How can I pass an Array into a Laravel Controller

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a number of arrays within my Laravel view that I would like to pass into the controller. These arrays should not be modified by the user, and are only there because they are passed from another method in the controller, (the view is acting as  abridge between the controller methods).  I'm not sure what the best practice to accomplish this is.

TLDR: Trying to pass `$info_array` from View to `process_logs` method in `GameController`

`View`

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'admin/games/process']) !!}

@foreach ($players_array as $game)
    <h4>Round {{$round}}</h4>

    <div class="form-group">

        @foreach($game as $player)
            <p><strong>{{ $player }}</strong></p>

            <!-- This chunk might be able to be written cleaner using laravelcollective/html -->
            <select name="round_{{$round}}[{{str_replace("]", "fstupidkey", $player)}}]">
                @foreach($all_players as $key=>$p)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $p }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>

        @endforeach
    </div>
    <!-- {{ $round++ }} -->

@endforeach

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Submit Refactored Players', ['class' => 'btn btn-outline-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

`Controller`

```
  public function process_logs(Request $request){
        /*
         * Accept player match arrays from user form
         * Input event data into database
         */


    $a = $request->round_1;

    /*
    * Create new array to put shit in..
    */
    $b = [];

    foreach($a as $key=>$item){
        $c = str_replace("fstupidkey", "]", $key);
        $b[$c] = $item;
    }

    dd(Session::get('info_array'));

    dd($request->all());

}
```

`Routes`

```
Route::post('admin/games/process', 'GameController@process_logs');
```

Comment: If you are needing to send data between controller methods, you likely have an issue with your design. If this data must persist between requests, it is better stored in either a cache, session or a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$info_array` is just an array, you can serialize it and pass in hidden input:

```
{!! Form::hidden('info', json_encode($info_array)) !!}
```

And unserialize it in the controller:

```
$info_array = json_decode($request->info, true);
```

If you need more security, you can use [`encrypt()` and `decrypt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/encryption#using-the-encrypter) helpers.